# Loading Special Character via Polybase

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage, azure-synapse, polybase

I am trying to load single quote string delimited file and I am able to load data except for certain records for the string which contains below format. How to Load this below values using PolyBase in SQL Datawarehouse. Any input is highly appreciated.

**Eg:**

```
'Don''t Include'
'1'''
'Can''t'
'VM''s'
```

**External File Format:**

```
CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT SAMPLE_HEADER
with (format_type=delimitedtext,
format_options(
FIELD_TERMINATOR=',',
STRING_DELIMITER='''',
DATE_FORMAT='yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss',
USE_TYPE_DEFAULT=False)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case your string delimiter needs to be something other than a single quote.

I assume you're using a comma-delimited file. You have a couple of options:

- Make your column delimiter something other than comma.
- Make your string delimiter a character that does not exist in your data
- Use an output format other than CSV, such as Parquet or Orc

If you're going to use a custom delimiter, I suggest ASCII Decimal(31) or Hex(0x1F), which is specifically reserved for this purpose.

If you're going to use a string delimiter you might use double-quote (but I'm guessing this is in your data) or choose some other character.

That said, my next guess is that you're going to come across data with embedded carriage returns, and this is going to cause yet another layer of problem. For that reason, I suggest you move your extracts to something other than CSV, and look to Parquet or Orc.

Comment: Thanks Ron for your suggestion. The Double single quote('') is present in the data file. I tried using 0x27 as well but It didn't help me. I am using BLOB storage in my test so, I am not sure whether I can convert this CSV to other format files. Is there any way to skip if there is continuous double single quote in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Polybase in SQLDW [does not support](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-sql-data-warehouse/suggestions/10600132-polybase-allow-field-row-terminators-within-strin) handling of the escape character in the delimited text format. So you cannot load your file directory in SQLDW.

In order to load your file, you may pre-process your input file. During pre-processing you may generate another data file either in binary format (PARQUET or ORC which are directory readable by poly-base) or another delimited file with some special field separator(any character which is not expected in your data file, e.g. | or ~). With such special character, there is no need of using escaping/delimiting the values)

Hope its helps.

[From Azure docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-file-format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
<format_options> ::=  
{  
    FIELD_TERMINATOR = field_terminator  
    | STRING_DELIMITER = string_delimiter 
    | First_Row = integer -- ONLY AVAILABLE SQL DW
    | DATE_FORMAT = datetime_format  
    | USE_TYPE_DEFAULT = { TRUE | FALSE } 
    | Encoding = {'UTF8' | 'UTF16'} 
}
```